# How to re-run an event function after a condition has been met?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to have a sidebar scroll at a slower rate until it reaches a certain point. The sidebar is then supposed to stop scrolling as the user reaches that set point. Here's my jQuery code:

```
$(window).on("scroll", function() {
    var sidebar = $('.sidebar');
    var stopPoint = $('#stop-point');
    var sidebarBottom = sidebar.offset().top + sidebar.height();
    var stopPointBottom = stopPoint.offset().top + stopPoint.height() - 30; 

    if (sidebarBottom > stopPointBottom) {
        $('.sidebar').css({'top' : "288px"});
    }
    else {
        $('.sidebar').css({'top' : ($(this).scrollTop()/3)+"px"});
    }
});
```

Everything is working great while the ELSE condition is the case. The issue is when the IF condition is met, then the sidebar stays stuck at its lowest point even if I scroll back up and the ELSE condition is again met.

I'd be grateful if someone could help me understand what I'm doing wrong, and if there's a smarter way to achieve the same.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Eww, [don't scroll hijack](https://envato.com/blog/scroll-hijacking/)

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is interested here's how I've fixed it:

```
$(window).on("scroll", function() {
    var sidebar = $('.sidebar');
    var stopPoint = $('#stop-point');
    var sidebarBottom = sidebar.offset().top + sidebar.height();
    var stopPointBottom = stopPoint.offset().top + stopPoint.height() - 30; 

    $('.sidebar').css({'top' : ($(this).scrollTop()/3)+"px"});

    if (($(this).scrollTop()/3) > 284 ) {
        $('.sidebar').css({'top' : "284px"});
    }
});
```

When scrolling back to the top the sidebarBottom was bigger by a few pixels than stopPointBottom so the condition was impossible to meet.